# label localization C#

Tags: c#, localization, label, translation

I have a `Windows Form`, and I want to translate with the `localization`. I know how to do this with the interface, but not with the code.
For example, I have this `label` :

```
Label la = new Label();
la.Text = "Hello world";
this.panel1.Controls.Add(la);
```

I want write a traduction, so I would have something like this :

```
For French : la.Text = "Bonjour tout le monde";
For English : la.Text = "Hello world";
```

It is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Resources file. Put all your strings into it. Then use them in your code like that:

```
la.Text = Resources.FrenchLaText;
```